# How do I ensure that one thread always run ahead of other in java? Given two threads. I need to make sure that Thread 1 always leads Thread 2

Tags: java, multithreading

Given two threads.
Thread 1 : prints from 1 to 100
Thread 2 : prints from 1 to 100
I need to make sure that Thread 1 never prints any number which is not yet printed by Thread 2.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.
(-- was asked in my interview with Wissen Technology)

I tried below approach.

```
package threadTutor;

public class ThreadLeader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Leader lead = new Leader(100);
        Follower foll = new Follower(100);
        foll.start();
        lead.start();
        foll.join();
        lead.join();        
    }

}

class Leader extends Thread{
    static int start;
    static int end;
    static int pos;
    Leader(int end){
        Leader.end = end;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i=start;i<end;i++) {
            System.out.println("Leader is printing "+i);
            Leader.pos=i;
        }
    }
}
class Follower extends Thread{
    static int start;
    static int end;
    static int pos;
    Follower(int end){
        Follower.end = end;
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(Follower.pos<=Leader.pos) {
                System.out.println("Follower is printing "+pos);
                pos++;
            }
            if(Follower.pos==Follower.end) break;
        }       
    }
}
```

but ofcourse infinite while loop is not a good way of doing things.
Please help with a better approach.

Comment: Going by the details of your question, what user207421 indicated is correct. However, if you go by the subject line of your question, which is more general. the answer is you cannot ensure such a thing unless there is come external controller (by some means) and largely dependent on your design. For example, if it is a multi object call and the state of the objects can be changed externally and the threads depend on that state, then thread 2 may very well skip a object call based on the state and go ahead of thread1. java.util.concurrentpackage has mechanisms bywhich control canbe established.

Comment: Hint: there is absolutely no need to make the fields in your two classes **static**. I suggest you learn about super basic things, too. Well, honestly: learn about these basics before turning to more advanced topics like concurrency.

Comment: Two semaphores.  Thread 1 waits on sema A, prints, posts to sema B.  Thread 2 waits on sema B, prints, posts to sema A.   Create the threads, nothing will happen because both threads are waiting.  Then post a unit to sema B and watch 'em go:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consumer-producer problem. Folloing is a blocking queue implementation. Other options:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/

```java
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ThreadLeader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Leader lead = new Leader(queue, 100);
        Follower foll = new Follower(queue, 100);
        foll.start();
        lead.start();
        foll.join();
        lead.join();
    }

}

class Leader extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private int num;

    Leader(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue, int num) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Leader is printing " + i);
            queue.offer(i);
        }
    }
}

class Follower extends Thread {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private int num;

    Follower(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue, int num) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            try {
                System.out.println("Follower is printing " + queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. But isn't the logic same here as well? You are running an infinite for loop. What would happen if control switches to follower thread and there is nothing to print, won't it just keep on executing infinitely before the control switches back to Leader? Or am I missing something?

Comment: you can add a counter to Follower loop, such as `for(int i =0; i <100; i++)`.The Follower will be block when  it behind Leader(block when `queue.take` execute ). The difference from your code is that the Follower thread does not occupy cpu time.